# Rails searchkick aggregation of has_many_through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aggregation, searchkick

I have an ecommerce product catalogue, where I store products, product options and option values in this kind of fashion:

```
# models/product.rb
has_many :option_values
has_many :option_types, through: :option_values

# models/option_value.rb
belongs_to :option_type
belongs_to :product

#models/option_type.rb
has_many :option_values
has_many :products
```

I came up with this structure so I can have for example a lamp `Product` that can be connected to `OptionType` titled "Power supply included" via value `OptionValue` set to `true`. Data in database for this product are saved as follows:

```
#products
id: 22
title: "A lamp"

#option_values
id: 1
option_type_id: 5
product_id: 22
value: true

#option_types
id: 5
title: "Power supply included"
```

Every `ProductCategory` has its own specific set of option values, that's why I came up with this structure, it is inspired by Spotify architecture and I will need this in search/aggregates/filters, what leads me to my question:

How can i create aggregate search so I can select all products, that have "Power supply included" set to true? Do I need nested aggregates, or do I setup `search_data` in some fashion so I can access them via `aggs`?

I am basically creating a search filter feature, where customer can check between these `OptionTypes`. For example - product, with "Included power supply set to TRUE", "Bulp mount set to E27". And so on.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you will probably have a bunch of `option_types`, and they may even be dynamic? If so, search data is probably not a good fit, as you'd have to define a new field for every such type. I'd say `aggs` is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, there is bunch of `option_values` connected to `Product`. And those `option_values` are connected to `option_types`. It might seem complicated but in my opinion it's pretty much standard way of organizing such data. 

That is my question - if I can do it with aggregates (`aggs`) or do I setup `search_data` for the `Product` model. In both scenarios, I need and advice on how to do it as well :)